# Update CSV using Varien_File_Csv();

Tags: csv

I am using *Varien_File_Csv* to save CSV data.

```
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->saveData($fileName, $data);
```

This approach always rewrites the CSV output file. Is there any way to use append method to output file instead of rewrite?

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite the CSV output file" ? What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: I reckon there's no need to extend the class, it already provides a high number of public methods to specify the CSV parameters.

Comment: To use append mode instead of rewrite to output file.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no public methods which should be used for this purpose.

Comment: I found Varien_File_Csv to not be useful at all in most cases and would recommend to use SplFileObject (or a custom solution) instead. I explained it in detail at http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2015/03/csv-processing-with-magento/

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, by extending the class Varien_File_Csv, and rewriting the method `saveData` to change:

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'w');
```

to

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'a');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rewriting the class you could also have done:

```
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
// Get original data
$orgData = $csv->getData($fileName);
$csv->saveData($fileName,$orgData);
$csv->saveData($fileName,$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the Varien_File_Csv will do the trick. I opened mine to allow all fopen file modes

```
class Custom_File_Csv extends Varien_File_Csv
{
    /**
     * Overrides saveData function with file options
     *
     * @param [type] $file
     * @param [type] $data
     * @param string $fileoption
     * @return void
     */
    public function saveData($file, $data, $fileoption = 'w')
    {
        $fh = fopen($file, $fileoption);
        foreach ($data as $dataRow) {
            $this->fputcsv($fh, $dataRow, $this->_delimiter, $this->_enclosure);
        }
        fclose($fh);
        return $this;
    }
}
```